# Access doesn't hold datatype for column

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a local table and a query in MS Access application. Query populates the table with values, and the table has a column whose return type value should be double, i set the Field Size as Double, but on running the application, it automatically changes the Field Size for that column to Decimal with upto 2 Decimal places. I don't want that column to have round off values.

For Instance: A value 12.44556 is output as 12.44.

How can i enforce Access to use Double as Field Size ? Access at the moment, overrides the Field Size that i set.

Any Ideas, i am kinda lost ?

I have a very straight forward SQL.

```
SELECT A,B,C,D 
INTO TABLE_TEST 
FROM TESTABC
```

Where TABLE_TEST is a local table, and TESTABC is SQL db table.

Also, after this i am updating the column, with certain multiplications like the following.

```
Update TABLE_TEST
SET B= A/C*D
```

A,B,C and D all should have Field Size as Double, Even when i set it as Double, on running, Access changes it back to Decimal. :\

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at a storage format, and not a *display* format?

Comment: I am setting Field Size, by going to table design view, and setting Field Properties. So i believe it is storage format.

Comment: Check the `Format` property of the field.  Make sure it's blank.

Comment: Yes, it's blank. The thing which is bothering me is if i have set "Double" as Field Size, why would access change it to Decimal with round 2 values.

Comment: Is there already data in the table?

Comment: No, i tried with removing all the data from table.

Comment: I suppose you're doing a make table query somewhere ?

Comment: Make table query? My query is like this Select A, B, C into TABLE_TEST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties should be like so:

[image: double data type]

Resulting in:

[image: double data]

To create this from a query, you can use, something on the lines of:

```
SELECT Table1.AText, CDbl([ANumeric]/2) AS Expr1 INTO b
FROM Table1;
```

`CDbl` will ensure you get a double returned.

Comment: Yes, the issue is even if set a field to Double, on running a query, i get result set as decimals, and also the Table overrides my setting and sets the Field Size back to Decimal, on its own.

Comment: Please add the sql for your query to your question.

Comment: Thanks, your tip worked like magic. Cdbl forced double output as required. :)

Answer (score 3):

SELECT INTO creates a new table.  If you want to add records to an existing table (with predefined data types), you should use an APPEND query.

Comment: No, i intend to create a new table, every time the application is run.

Comment: Then you have to live with the data type that Access selects.  Instead of doing that, create the table the way you want it, run a DELETE query to clear out the old records, and an APPEND query to insert the new ones.

Comment: I see, so isn't there anyway to pre-define the data type ? Actually i am updating an existing application, and it used to produce "Double" datatype outputs. I just updated the query by adding some joins, and since then the access is producing "Decimal" datatypes everywhere, where it was producing "Double" values earlier.

Comment: The way you pre-define the data type in Access is by  creating the table manually, specifying the data types, and then preserving the original table structure thereafter.  AFAIK there's no way to specify the data type in a MAKE TABLE/SELECT INTO query; it's all auto-sensed.

Comment: Thanks for providing the insight, this information is really helpful.

Comment: I see Remou found a way.  I forgot about `CDbl`.  It's a shame you have to convert every value to a double just to auto-sense the creation field type. :)  Although I suppose the overhead is minimal.

Comment: I would prefer the insert you suggested, which is why I voted for this answer, and I am a bit suspicious of creating a new table each time, but there you are. :)

Comment: Well definitely, Creating a new table is a more cleaner method and will bring it to practice. But my curious mind likes finding answers to questions, even if they are not very great. Thanks, i learnt something useful today.